# why my 1d fourier transform gives identical output

Tags: python, fft

I am trying to implement fourier transform according to the following formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform):

[image]

So I do:

```
import numpy as np

def fft1d(data):
    result = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        result.append(data[i] * np.exp(-2 * np.pi * 1j * i))

    return np.array(result)
```

and when I give it some random audio:

```
IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Audio(input_audio, rate=audio_rate))
plt.plot(input_audio)

arr = fft1d(input_audio)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(arr.real)
plt.plot(arr.imag)
```

I got:

[image]

But I was expecting something similar to the result of `np.fft.fft()`:

[image]

May I know what did I do wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: i think first you should be aware you cant implement continuous fourier transform with a computer which works discretely. you need to look DFT which is also what numpy calculates. its formula might tell you whats wrong

Comment: There is no sum, so no integral in your algorithm. Nor there is no new variable "xi".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, I misread the formula, I should be implementing the [discrete fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) instead:

[image]

So:

```
def fft1d(data):
    max_freq = len(data)
    
    result = []
    
    for freq in range(max_freq):
        total = 0
        for i in range(len(data)):
            total += data[i] * np.exp(-1j * 2 * np.pi / len(data) * freq * i)
        result.append(total)
        
    return np.array(result)
```

So now I get the correct result:

[image]